# I don't understand module_load_include()

Tags: 7

I believe it is meant to be used as follows, in loading a module include file into the calling scope:

```
function mymodule1_myfunction1(){
    ...
    module_load_include($type, $module, $name);
    ...
}
```

But looking at the code of `module_load_include()`:

```
function module_load_include($type, $module, $name = NULL) {
  static $files = array();

  if (!isset($name)) {
    $name = $module;
  }

  $key = $type . ':' . $module . ':' . $name;
  if (isset($files[$key])) {
    return $files[$key];
  }

  if (function_exists('drupal_get_path')) {
    $file = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . drupal_get_path('module', $module) . "/$name.$type";
    if (is_file($file)) {
      require_once $file;
      $files[$key] = $file;
      return $file;
    }
    else {
      $files[$key] = FALSE;
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

We see that

`require_once $file`

is used to load `$file` into the scope of `module_load_include()`,  not  `mymodule1_myfunction1()` so `$file` is not available to `mymodule1_myfunction1()`. Is this not how `module_load_include()` is meant to be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We see that `require_once $file` is used to load $file into the scope of module_load_include()

Not quite. This is from the [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) docs (identical to `require` in this respect)

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. However, **all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope**.

Emphasis mine.

So functions/classes defined in an a file sourced with include/require will be available to all subsequent code. Or more specifically, all functions/class defined in the file you include via `module_load_include` will be available in `mymodule1_myfunction1()` after the call.